# Web2Py Application - Server IP variable instead of: 192.168.178.46:8000, 192.168.178.53:8000 and pythonanywhere

Tags: json, web2py, pythonanywhere

When starting up web2py locally I can select an IP address and port e.g.  192.168.178.46:8000 or 192.168.178.53:8000 etc.

When using Web2Py with json, currently I am using the hard coded IP address:

```
d3.json("http://192.168.178.46:8000/web2pyappname/default/
rt_batt_data_json_xml_hmtl_dViz.json")  
   .then(function(json_array){ .....
```

In case starting up different, the IP address this code has to be changed.

Is there a variable ( etc) that retrieves the IP address and can be used instead of (to be put directly in the weblink)?

The same, when using/deploying on pythonanywhere (the current problem)?

```
https://user_subdomain.pythonanywhere.com/admin/default
  /design/web2pyappname
```

Whilst navigating through the web2py app works fine, 
I already get an error message when trying to access a db-table
    invalid view (default/rt_batt_data_json_xml_hmtl_dViz.json)

Or is this done in a different way as a service (which then already should be used when developing locally)?

In case its already answered in detail, a weblink has to fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a relative URL:

```
d3.json("/web2pyappname/default/rt_batt_data_json_xml_hmtl_dViz.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

The relative URL, it's working as recommended on the local PC. It has been tested in detail. Thank you very much.

((On pythonanywhere it does not work right now but there, already the used json view is not working. Therefore I have to investigate further and most realistic, later a question hast to be put.

```
def rt_batt_data_json_xml_hmtl():
  battdat = db().select(db.csv_rt_bat_c3.rec_time,   
    db.csv_rt_bat_c3.cellnr, db.csv_rt_bat_c3.volt_act,
    db.csv_rt_bat_c3.id).as_list()
  return dict(battdat=battdat)
```

))